# How do I render JSX based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add something like:

```
if(true) <Reminder /> else <div>hehe</div>
```

In  ordinary way? I know, I can create two `return` statements with `<Reminder />` and without `<Reminder />`, but I don't want to repeat code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  renderReminders() {
    const { reminders } = this.props;
    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {
          reminders.map(reminder => {
            return (
              <ListGroupItem key={reminder.id}>
                <div>{reminder.text}</div>
                <Reminder dueDate={reminder.dueDate} />
              </ListGroupItem>
            )
          })
        }
      </ListGroup>
    ) // return 
  } // renderReminders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
{condition ?
  <div>I will render when condition is true!</div>
    :
  <div>I will render when condition is false!</div>
}
```

This will use an inline JSX expression to conditionally render JSX based on `condition`. For example:

```
return (
  <ListGroupItem key={reminder.id}>
    <div>{reminder.text}</div>
    {true ? 
      <Reminder dueDate={reminder.dueDate} />
        :
      <div>Hehe!</div>
    }
  </ListGroupItem>
)
```